# How can I make GitHub Dependency graph/Used by indicator list dependencies on Maven sub modules?

Tags: maven, github, pom.xml, dependency-management

I've noticed that the new "Used by" indicator on GitHub shows up on [my project pages](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys). However, nobody (well, actually, there is one single project) has dependencies directly on the parent project, dependencies are typically on the sub modules. So the indicator looks kind of silly and does not reflect the real usage of the project. The same issue applies for the ["Dependency graph"](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/network/dependents), which also lists the same lonely project.

The project uses Maven for project definition (`pom.xml`), and it seems like that's what GitHub picks up and uses for determining dependencies.

How can I configure this GitHub functionality, so that it also covers dependencies on the sub modules? Or alternatively, is it possible to configure what modules should be used for the dependency tracking? I do find it a bit strange that GitHub don't do this automatically, given the popularity of Maven projects, and this being a very standard Maven setup. Is there something I can do to the Maven POM to help/force GitHub do what I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is now how GitHub works as standard, but at least I talked to GitHub support, and they fixed the issue for my project, by adding the dependencies for the sub modules.